# User token in Backand

Tags: hosting, backand

Recently the BaaS provider Backand started providing hosting in their service. However I'm trying to deploy my project using the information at Backand.com, and running into an issue. The documentation says the deployment code is:

```
backand sync --app <app_name> --master <app master token> --user <user token> --folder </path/to/project/folder> \
```

I'm confused, though. Where do I get the user token? Is that a value I make up, or is it on the dashboard somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i've just seen in the docs the following lines which describes where you can get the option values:

--app: The current app name
--master: The master token of the app (get it from Social & Keys)
--user: The token of the current user (get it from Team and click on key icon)
--folder: The path of the local Angular folder to sync and deploy

hope it will help you !

Answer (score 0):

You Just had to follow these Simple Steps..

```
1. Go to the Backand Dashboard    
2. Navigate **Security & Auth**     
3. Then Click on **Team** , you will see the users registered in your team.    
4. Click on key icon & you will get your --user Token
```